# Race condition when updating table

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I have a game, and 2 players play with each other via websockets using mysql to store game state.  Players submit their moves at the same time and the server should respond accordingly:

Scenario: Player1 submits a turn.  The server checks the database to see what the most recent turn was and:

- If both players submitted an action for that turn, it will create a
  new turn with Player1's action input.
- If the most recent turn does not have an action for Player1, it will
  update the action in the database and then act out the game.
- If the most recent turn has no input for player2 but it does have an input for player1, it should just update the database and then wait for player2 to make a response.

The problem arises when Player1 submits his turn, player2 submits their turn, and then both selects fire at very nearly the same time.  This will result in 2 turns being inserted into the database and then the game has no idea that both players have submitted their turns (as each believes them to have created a new turn).

Here is the turn table:

- Id (int) - Primary Key
- GameId (int) - Foreign Key to the game    table, a game can have
  several turns
- Turn Number (int) - Indicates    which turn this table represents.
- Player1Action (varchar) - The    action player 1 has taken.
- Player2Action (varchar) - The action    player 2 has taken.

I am not sure how to proceed without exposing this race condition.  None of the columns except for the primary key can be unique so I cannot check that way, and if there were some way of preventing multiple inserts to an existing GameId / TurnNumber combination, the server would need to know in order to prevent default execution.

The project uses ASP.NET MVC4 and SignalR as a websocket protocol, if that helps at all.

EDIT:

I am aware of creating a composite unique index on the table between the GameId and TurnNumber but this will not indicate to the caller that there was an insert collision.

Here is an example (very simplified) execution code:

```
var turns = new List<Turn>();
var query = "select * from Turn where GameId = @id order by TurnNumber asc";
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection())
{
    using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand(conn, query))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", gameId);
        try
        {
            using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(reader.read())
                {
                     turns.Add(//Get Reader Data to make turn);
                }
            }
        }
        //Handle exceptions
    }
}
var lastTurn = turns[turns.Count - 1];

//This turn is old
if(TurnIsOld(lastTurn))
{
    //Create new turn and insert
    return;
}
//Player 1 has not taken an action
else if(Player1NoAction(turn))
{
    //Update the turn
    ExecuteGame(turns);
}
//Thus player 2 must have not taken an action
else
{
    //Update player 1 action
    return;
}
```

The problem exists in that both player 1 and player 2 can execute the first if-condition when they make their turn decisions at roughly the same time as the other player's if-condition block has not yet finished executing.

Comment: Consider to show your current code

Comment: There's too much to fit here but I will see what I can do.

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at the code. Generally, in order to prevent race conditions, a manual write lock must be acquired on some record somewhere in the transaction. Most likely on the record retrieved in the first step: `The server checks the database to see what the most recent turn was`. What type of isolation level is used ?

Comment: I've updated my original statement with a simplified code execution, hopefully that clears some things up.

Comment: there is none, i'm not quite sure what an isolation level is or how to use one.